# Not another beamer footnote cite minipage question

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, minipage

### Problem

I know similar questions have been asked many times before, but I think this case is unique (happy to be proved wrong).

I want to simply write `\cite{name}` in my Beamer presentation, no matter if I'm in a `minipage` or not, and have some short info about the reference appear in the *frame footnote*, plus the full citation at the end of the presentation via `\printbibliography`. I don't want to tinker with case-specific `\footnotemark` / `footnotetext`, etc. I am also interested in printing the footnote reference info *inline* like the `para` option from [`footmisc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) (to use less space). Finally, regular footnotes should be unaffected.

### Question

After much effort, I have a working solution (below), but my question is: how can my solution be improved? e.g.:

- Have I done anything "bad"?
- Does anything break in other use cases?
- Can we make it work with hyperref?
- Can we use citecolor appropriately?
- Do we care that all the citations come at the end? (I prefer it)

Thanks

### Working Solution

```
\documentclass[20pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe}
% SOLUTION
\makeatletter
\def\empty{} % dummy
\newcounter{cite}% count citations per frame
% prepend reset stuff to begin frame
\let\xbeamer@frameslide\beamer@frameslide
\def \beamer@frameslide{%
  \let\ffn\empty\setcounter{cite}{0}%
  \xbeamer@frameslide}
% prepend footnote stuff to end frame
\let\xendbeamer@frameslide\endbeamer@frameslide
\def \endbeamer@frameslide{%
  % add a footnote (no number) if \ffn is not empty
  \ifx\ffn\empty\else{\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{\ffn}}\fi%
  \xendbeamer@frameslide}
% redefine \cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{%
  % step & print the counter
  \stepcounter{cite}\textsuperscript{\alph{cite}}
  % add to \ffn: the cite counter (not footnote) and \textcite (black magic)
  \edef\fntext{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\ffn{%
    \noexpand\textsuperscript{\alph{cite}}\textcite{#1}\enspace}}\fntext}
\makeatother
% EXAMPLE
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Hello World}
    before minipage\footnote{First footnote}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\color{red}
      inside minipage: pen\cite{Hello} apple\cite{World}
    \end{minipage}
    after minipage\footnote{Second footnote}
    pineapple\cite{World}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{References}\printbibliography\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

mwe.bib is:

```
@article{Hello,author={Hello},title={Hello},journal={Hello},year={1999}}
@article{World,author={World},title={World},journal={World},year={2020}}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Update: this solution does not work with `\pause`, etc. I think because we do the processing at `\endbeamer@frameslide`, which maybe needs to be a different hook?